# Is it possible to run rrdtool serverside?

Tags: server, rrdtool

Have searched, but not found an answer.

Presently running RRDTool at the same processor which is collecting the information, making rrd-files and related graphic output at that processor.

Is it also possible to run ***RRDTool at a server*** for graphic output, applying rrd-files being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; at least to some extent.  You need to run `rrdcached` on your backend server; then, your collector and graphing servers can make remote calls to obtain or store the data.

How you tune `rrdcached` depends on the amount of data and frequency of writes, and how much you can afford to lose in the even of a server crash; however generally a 30min cache works.  This also greatly decreases the amount of disk IO required.

Note that some `rrdtool` functions do not work exactly the same via `rrdcached`; check the documentation for more details.

Read about `rrdcached` here: https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcached.en.html